# Change default music app used by ES File Explorer

Tags: default-applications, es-file-explorer

I tried to change the default music app executed with ES File Explorer with not success. I tried to clear the data of the app, uninstall and install again and set the default music app with Default App Manager.

Is it possible to set the default music app for ES File Explorer?

Answer (score 1):

What's the app that is currently launched when you open a music for in ES? Find that app in the Settings > Apps and tap on Clear defaults (not Clear data). Note that you need to clear defaults on the music player app, not on ES File Explorer.

Alternatively, you can go to ES Settings (open ES, then tap on the icon to the left of the current folder path, then tap on Settings on the bottom) > Cleanup settings > Clear defaults.

Comment: The music is played with ES Explorer itself. I tried your second solution. Now, if I click on a music file, I can choose a different player. **But if I select a folder and play it, it is still played with ES Explorer (it should be the default action for ES Explorer)**

Comment: Why you want to select the folder in ES ? Just go to your music player and select the folder there. All modern music players have this feature of selecting a folder to play the songs!!.
Phonograph is a music player that i use.

Comment: @rajatpunkstaa Not every player allows browsing to network located files. ES can choose them there and play. It also may use another player, but is limited, can't send to jetAudio for example.
To choose another player means to cut out esteemed feratures

Answer (score 0):

Steps to change default music player

Select Mp3 file>tap and open as >>Select app to open mp3>> Tick Set as default .

Attached >Gif 
[image]